# How to plot deviation above and below the line x=y line in a figure?

Tags: python, plot

I have plotted data using python. Following is an excerpt from the code:

```
#matplotlib 

ax = df.plot.scatter(x = 'exp_CO', y = 'sim_CO',s=30, color='g' )


#plot the line of correlation:x=y
lims = [
    np.min([ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()]),  # min of both axes
    np.max([ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()]),  # max of both axes
]


# now plot both limits against eachother
ax.plot(lims, lims, 'k-', alpha=0.75, zorder=0)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(lims)
ax.set_ylim(lims)

plt.title('experimental $^{13}{CO}$ chemical shift (ppm) vs simulated $^{13}{CO}$ chemical shift (ppm)')
plt.xlabel('exp_CO',weight='semibold', size = 20)
plt.ylabel('sim_CO',weight='semibold', size = 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to plot a line below and above the x=y line, which will essentially indicate an error of say 2.45 above and below the said line.
This is how the plot should look like where the distance of pink lines above and below from the middle line should cover the 2.45:

[image]

How do I plot this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just add this:

```py
plt.plot(lims, lims - 2.45, color="r")
plt.plot(lims, lims + 2.45, color="r")
```

Comment: This is not working, unfortunately. It shows error of this type: typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just want two more lines next to your `x=y` line, where you subtract your "interval-width". I do not have your data, so I generated my own to give a complete example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lin_x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, lin_x.shape[0])
noise_std = np.std(noise) # In your case this may be =2.45

plt.close()
plt.plot(lin_x)
plt.scatter(range(lin_x.shape[0]), lin_x+noise)
plt.plot(lin_x + 2.*noise_std, c='pink')
plt.plot(lin_x - 2.*noise_std, c='pink')
plt.show()
```

[image: example figure]